# Не компилируется sass

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, gulp, sass

Подскажите пожалуйста, не компилируется sass в css.
Установил gulp, sass, прописал таск. Но когда пишу в sass файле код, то создается файл css, но пустой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не добавили ./ перед `app/sass/main.sass`

поделюсь свои gulpfile`ом

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var reload      = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./media/css/mainstyle.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./media/css'));
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    },
    port: 8080,
    open: true,
    notify: false
  });
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('./index.html')
  .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('server', function () {
  gulp.watch('./media/css/mainstyle.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./index.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['server', 'browserSync']);
```

Comment: С точкой аналогичная ситуация

Comment: @СергейСочиенко а как вы запускаете компиляцию?